# Axios async / await problem in a vuejs method

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, async-await, axios

I have the following method in a Vue.js application:

```
register: async function () {
  const data = await Api.register(this.userMail, this.password)
  if (data.status === 200) {
    this.$session.set('userToken', data.data.token)
  } else {
    // do something else
  }
}
```

Api.register(params) is an API call made with axios:

```
register (userMail, password) {
    return axios.post('http://localhost:8081/authentification/register', {userMail: userMail, password: password})
  }
```

My API is completely working with the values I've used to test it with Postman but I have the following error with my Vue.js application:

`[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler (Promise/async): "TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined"`

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined`

I've tried to figure out where it comes from but I can't find

Could you please help me

Comment: the error was coming from here, thank's a lot 

Comment: Well the first thing to do would be to set a break point on `if (data.status === 200)` and see what the value of `data` actually is. or `console.log(data)`

Comment: Also just throwing out *authentification* isn't a word.... its *authentication*

Comment: Is far as I remember, axios returns a promise, not the actual data. Try to do `if (await data.status === 200)`

Comment: The only `data` property access that you're doing in the code you've provided is in `data.data.token`, but the first `data` can't be undefined here because of the `if` statement condition. The error is occurring elsewhere. In the dev tools debugger, enable "Pause on exceptions" and "Pause on caught exceptions" then reproduce the error. It'll break on the exact line of code.

Comment: did you solve it?